# fetch is not giving the correct JSON response in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to use fetch method on API endpoint but I am getting some unexpected error. I am not able to view JSON data in my brower's console.

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `data` json object ?

Comment: The first step would be to check the response in the network tab or on the server. What ever that is, it's not JSON.

Comment: @Striped Check it out I have added.

Comment: @stonerock: A screenshot of text is not useful; as Andreas said, clearly what's coming back isn't JSON. It could be JSON marked up as HTML, for instance (making the first character `<`, probably, which would fit the error message). Also, is that URL what you're really using? Because `localhost:3000/data` looks odd, I'd expect at least `//localhost:3000/data`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check it out.

Comment: @Andreas check this https://imgur.com/a/InZqD

Comment: @stonerock: `www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1` also looks weird. Again, I'd expect `//www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1` at least.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/InZqD

Comment: @stonerock: Just because it returned the right content type, that doesn't mean it's valid JSON. Look for (say) invisible characters, a prefix of some kind, etc., etc. Fundamentally, this comes down to: Believe the tool. It's [not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). So find out what's wrong with the response.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check this http://iodocs.apps.intermine.org/yeastmine/docs#/ws-quick-search/GET/search In parameters q type in BRCA1 and run to see json

Comment: @stonerock: That tells us nothing, because the response it gives there is not necessarily the response is gives to you. Again: What you're getting back clearly has an invalid character at line 1, column 1. It's down to you to find out why that is.

Comment: The screenshot shows `localhost`, your example uses `flymine.org`. What's the real setup of the request... - Nevertheless the `fetch(...)` with flymine.org (after fixing the url) works without a parse error.

Comment: can you replace `.then(res => res.json())` with `.then(res => { console.log(res); return res.json(); })` and paste the result of the log?

Comment: @AyushGupta See screnshot: https://imgur.com/a/mIbcX

Comment: So it's your code at `localhost:3000` that's providing the response; that explains the weird URLs. Clearly, since the response from www.flymine.org is valid JSON (I checked), your code is inserting something in front of it (if I **guess** that your code is meant to do the request from your server and send back what it got, to work around the SOP).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am new to this and couldn't understand how to fix it.

Comment: @AyushGupta Any idea how to fix the error ?

Comment: @stonerock: I don't understand what you mean. Are you trying to **directly** query `www.flymine.org` from a browser? If so, then what I said in my first comment would be how you do it: *"Because `localhost:3000/data looks odd`, I'd expect at least `//localhost:3000/data`."* But that won't work either, because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am tryting to get data and see in console by directly fetching` www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1`

Comment: why many downvotes ? This is not repeated question. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the protocol `http://` before the URL, like:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're using a *page-relative* URL: `www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1`. That means that if you do that fetch, the full URL will be something like `http://localhost:3000/www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1`. Unless you're running a server on port 3000 that does web requests and returns the results, that's not the right URL.

To make it protocol-relative, put `//` in front of it. Then it'll take the protocol from the page (`http` or `https`) and add `//www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1` to it, giving us `http://www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1` or `https://www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1`. Or add `http://` in front of it to make it specifically `http` (since they don't support `https`):

```
fetch('http://www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

[Live Example on JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/yovoxiwora/)

Note that if you're doing this in a browser, the only reason it works is that they specifically allow all origins via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). If they didn't, you'd be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Crowder Good answer thanks. Why have someone downvoted me :(

Comment: @stonerock: Not *you*, your question. :-) The tooltip on the downvote button is all the explanation you're likely to get. Happy coding!

Comment: @TJ Crowder but this is not good I have not asked repeated question. If you like my question please do upvote.

Comment: @stonerock: Downvotes aren't about duplicates; again, see the tooltip. I'd also review the [help].

Comment: The resource OP is requesting does have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header btw

Comment: @AyushGupta: That's odd, when I tried to use it in jsFiddle I got an SOP error.

Comment: I'm doing `curl -v --url www.flymine.org/query/service/search?q=BRCA1`, that's where I see it

Comment: @AyushGupta: Doh! It's jsFiddle. jsFiddle uses `https` and disallows mixed-content; www.flymine.org doesn't support https. So the issue wasn't SOP, it was mixed content. I should have paid more attention. You're right, works just fine in JSBin.